# Check boolean from another function

Tags: python, boolean

I am trying to do something when a boolean from another function is set to "True". I tried using return(variable) but when it comes to the function that asks for the bool it always says False. I took a look here before asking this because I felt like this seems to be really basic stuff. But i couldn't find anything usefull. I hope someone can help me with this. 
Here is my code.

```
x = 0
bool = False

def functionA(x,bool):
    if x is 0:
        bool = True


def functionB(bool):
    print bool
    if bool is True:
        print "Halleluhja"



functionA(x,bool)
functionB(bool)

print x, bool
```

Comment: Do not make a variable named `bool`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That "bool" was just for the test purpose. Within my work I always try to use clear simple names for functions or variables. Should have done that here too!

Comment: For me, it is better understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking to how you've written your code, you have two options. Option 1 is to use a global variable, making sure you include the `global` declaration in functions where you want to modify it:

```
x = 0
bool = False

def functionA(x):
    global bool
    if x is 0:
        bool = True

def functionB():
    print bool
    if bool is True:
        print "Halleluhja"

functionA(x)
functionB()

print x, bool
```

Option 2 (preferred) is to actually return things so that they can be passed elsewhere:

```
x = 0

def functionA(x):
    if x is 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def functionB(bool):
    print bool
    if bool is True:
        print "Halleluhja"

bool = functionA(x)
functionB(bool)

print x, bool
```

Other than that, don't use the name `bool`, use `x == 0` rather than `x is 0`, `functionA` can be written as just `return x == 0`, use `if bool:` rather than `if bool is True:`, and use `snake_case` (`function_a`) rather than `camelCase`.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions:

> More precisely, all variable assignments in a function store the value in the local symbol table; whereas variable references first look in the local symbol table, then in the local symbol tables of enclosing functions, then in the global symbol table, and finally in the table of built-in names. Thus, global variables cannot be directly assigned a value within a function (unless named in a [global](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) statement), although they may be referenced.

Your assignment to `bool` in `functionA` creates a local variable in `functionA`; it does not assign to the global variable `bool`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, do  not use a variable named `bool`. It's reserved by Python, such as like `str,list,int` etc.

Second, `bool` is in global scope, so if you want to edit it in a function, you have to define it as `global`.

```
x = 0
bool1 = False

def functionA(x,bool):
    global bool1 #now we have access to bool1 variable which is in global scope
    if x is 0:
        bool1 = True


def functionB(bool):
    print (bool1)
    if bool is True:
        print ("Halleluhja")



functionA(x,bool1)
functionB(bool1)

print (x, bool1)
```

Output

```
>>> 
True
Halleluhja
0 True
>>>
```

Comment: It's really confusing to parse `bool` and `bool1`.